# Will a country take actions if I skip a return flight out but still leave still later via another flight?

Tags: finland, helsinki

I'm currently in Finland, Rovaniemi. I started from Mauritius, took BritishAirways to the UK (have a return ticket) then took two Finnair flights to Helsinki then Rovaniemi (return tickets here too).

At passport control I was asked for my return flights and dates.

Now I want to avoid returning through the UK and instead take a train to Helsinki from Rovaniemi, then use another airline to return to Mauritius via UAE. This flight will take off in the evening, compared to the original return flight which should leave in the morning. Also I'm going via train for the first leg (Rovaniemi to Helsinki).

Is there any issue if I take this route and not follow the one I mentioned at passport control when entering the country?

Comment: small aside, I loved Rovaniemi. Althuogh I was there in June so had no nighttime. Hope you get to see some auroras!

Comment: I can't find an official answer, but I was in the same situation some time ago. I did not have any problem entering back into the country the next time as long as you didn't overstay your immigration status.

Comment: To be clear: are you planning to leave on the same day as you originally planned, just later in the day?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No action will be taken in such cases.

Important is that there is no overstay or any other violation of the visa conditions (such as geographical restrictions).

A certain amount of flexibility for travel arrangements is given, important is that the main purpose of the visit is fulfilled. Where you go **after** leaving the Schengen Area is of no concern.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I needed to know. Awesome

Comment: While this answer is surely correct for the case at hand, readers should be aware that the UK is notorious for people getting in trouble by staying significantly longer than they originally stated, even though they did not overstay, because their initial claim is presumed to have been deceptive.  (For example, someone might say they're coming for two weeks, notice that they've been admitted for six months, and decide to stay for ten weeks.)  Other countries might do the same, though I have no idea whether Finland is such a country.